# Audit logging of HTTP calls in Azure using C#

Tags: c#, azure, logging

For our application we need to log all modifications of any ressource reaching back one year.
The application is a ASP.Net Core Application exposing simple REST endpoints with CRUD operations.
We have a couple of constraints

- Every ressource has its own HTTP endpoint.
- We need to log the state of the ressource after each modification.
- We need to easily retrieve a log for all modifications using the ressource type (which corresponds to the endpoint http://example.com/order, http://example.com/products, ...) and its ID
- Each http call may modify multiple ressources, as each endpoint accepts a List
- The application itself runs inside a Docker container in Azure
- We need to log up to 200k modifications per hour and up to 500k per day

We are already using Application Insights for monitoring, but as data may be sampled, this does not seem to fit.

Is there an Azure service that meets our requirements?

Comment: did you explore the ELK stack for this ? Logstash to ingest, Elastic search to query , kibana to visualize

Comment: You could use Azure Event Hub to ingest, azure data lake or blob for storage and use azure data lake analytics to query.